# Chart js Backgroundimage Scaling

Tags: javascript, background-image, chart.js, scaling

Hi i'm quite new to JS and looking for an easy way to show a custom map with my own backgroundimage and several points with x-y-coordinates on it.

At first it worked quite well using the "line"-chart-type of chart.js (v2.5) with disabled showScale()-option and fixed axes-max/min-values.

My problem is that the backgroundimage is not rescaling properly when i change the window-size or show/hide the legend of the chart.

Here is my JS-code for creating the chart:

```
function initMap() {
    scatterChart = new Chart(document.getElementById("scatterChart"), {
        responsive: true,
        type: 'line',
        data: {
            /*datasets: [
                {

                }
            ]
            */
        },
        showScale: false,
        options: {
            scales: {
                yAxes: [{
                    display: false,
                    ticks: {
                        max: y_max,
                        min: 0,
                        stepSize: 0.1
                    }
            }],
                xAxes: [{
                    display: false,
                    type: 'linear',
                    position: 'bottom',
                    ticks: {
                        max: x_max,
                        min: 0,
                        stepSize: 0.1
                    }
            }]
            },
            onClick: function (evt) {
                var activePoint = scatterChart.getElementAtEvent(evt);
            },
            legend: {
                position: 'right',
                labels: {
                    fontSize: 15
                }
            },
        }
    });
}
```

HTML:

```
<canvas id="scatterChart" style="width: 1920px; height: 1080px; background-image:url('media/map_background.jpg'); background-size: 100% 100%;"></canvas>
```

Here are two images showing the effect:

https://1drv.ms/i/s!As59C5Mmd0nahr1zP4rjwI5KobaM3Q

https://1drv.ms/i/s!As59C5Mmd0nahr10KwUCJ4wpvfn4_g

What can i do to get a proper rescaling (points should always be shown on the same position on the map regardless of windowsize or enabled/disabled legend)?

Comment: Can you provide your dataset so I can re-create this exactly how you have it?

Comment: And upload your background image as well.  I can't suggest a solution unless I have an example that I can work from.

Comment: Here you can see a screenshot of the dataset of one point:
 [dataset-screenshot](https://1drv.ms/i/s!As59C5Mmd0nahr11XKlyfp6aWhRlAA) I also added two pictures in my post above showing the effect. I hope this information is sufficient.

Comment: Have you tried using the `maintainAspectRatio` property and setting it to `true`?  That should hopefully fix your window resize issue.  The only way to fix the legend issue is to use a legend that is external to the `canvas` because the legend takes up space in the `canvas` so the chart is squished horizontally (there is no layering concept in a `canvas`).  See [this example](http://codepen.io/jordanwillis/pen/PpJjWK) for how to generate an external legend.  You must use the `legendCallback` property and the `.generateLegend()` prototype method.

Comment: That's the solution! Thanks! :)

Comment: Cool.  Let me submit this as an answer in case others in the future stumble across the question (because they have the same issue) and don't read through the comments.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the `maintainAspectRatio` property and setting it to `true`? That should hopefully fix your window resize issue.

The only way to fix the legend issue is to use a legend that is external to the `canvas` because the legend takes up space in the `canvas` so the chart is squished horizontally (there is no layering concept in a `canvas`). See [this example](http://codepen.io/jordanwillis/pen/PpJjWK) for how to generate an external legend.

You must use the `legendCallback` property and the `.generateLegend()` prototype method.